# Как получить текст, лежащий по ссылке, в Android?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть ссылка на интернет-ресурс, по которой лежит текст в формате json. Как по этой ссылке получить этот текст и в дальнейшем распарсить как json, чтобы использовать в своем коде (Java)?

Answer (score 1):

В строке result будет ваш текст:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(URL, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            Strint result = new String (responseBody);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Самым простым способом будет использовать [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) и любую библиотеку `JSON`  [moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi) или [gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Можно обойтись и без библиотек, но реализация запроса будет весьма громоздкой.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы пояснить, как именно правильно использовать retrofit в моем случае? (получить String содержимое веб-страницы)

Comment: Может эта статья хоть немного раскроет тему вопроса https://habr.com/ru/post/429058/

Answer (score 0):

Для получения html можно использовать [**OkHttp**](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
  }
}
```

А дальше воспользоваться [**Google Gson**](https://github.com/google/gson) см [англ гайд по gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples)

```
JsonObject convertedObject = new Gson().fromJson(json_string), JsonObject.class);

json_string = run(ссылка на json)

JsonObject = ваша *модель*
```